# combine multiple vector shapes with low wasted space

Tags: python, algorithm, vector-graphics

I have an algorithm written in Python that creates and outputs a large amount of vector shapes. These shapes are all roughly triangular. Currently each is saved as a separate dxf file. I now want to laser-cut them and I'd like to do it with minimal waste.

What I'm looking for is a way to combine them without an unreasonable amount of wasted space. An algorithm that produces the most efficient possible result would also be nice, but it certainly isn't necessary.

Comment: Sounds like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem, just more complicated ;-) It's a version of the bin packing problem, which is a NP-hard. Google "Panel Cutting Optimizer" or so for software that solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Optimal 2d shape layout for cutting sheet goods is a **hard** problem, with active research.  The "panel cutting" problem assumes rectangular shapes.  Non-rectangular shapes are much harder.

Try searching for "[shape nesting algorithms](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=shape+nesting+algorithms)".

Comment: Thanks! I'm mainly looking to avoid combining them by hand.

Comment: Maybe you can get "close enough" by putting a bounding box around each of your shapes and using one of the rectangular layout methods for the bounding boxes.